# Pandas - Interpolate based on previous behavior

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, interpolation

I have a datetime index pandas with hourly data that needs to be interpolated when `nans` exist. Sometimes 1 hour is missing and a linear interpolation would be enough, but sometimes it can be days, in which case I'd need it to consider the behavior it has had on the last week on average to fill the values. Any ideas on how to do this?

Right now I am using `df.interpolate(method="linear")` but I need to fix it so that it considers the average of the last seven days (with data) when there is a large gap (more than 3 consecutive hours). So for example, if `2017-07-02 04:00:00` is missing, and is a part of a large gap, it should fill the value with the average value that occurs everyday at 4 am between the days of `2017-06-25` and "2017-07-02".

This is an example dataset

```
                      D31    D32                                                                                                                       
time                                                                                                                                                    
2017-07-01 00:00:00  118.0  118.0                                                                                                                       
2017-07-01 01:00:00  126.0  126.0                                                                                                                       
2017-07-01 02:00:00   96.0   np.nan                                                                                                                       
2017-07-01 03:00:00   88.0   88.0                                                                                                                       
2017-07-01 04:00:00   76.0   76.0                                                                                                                       
2017-07-01 05:00:00   60.0   60.0                                                                                                                       
2017-07-01 06:00:00   59.0   59.0                                                                                                                       2017-07-01 07:00:00   53.0   53.0                                                                                                                          
2017-07-01 08:00:00   54.0   54.0                                                                                                                       
2017-07-01 09:00:00   47.0   47.0                                                                                                                       
2017-07-01 10:00:00   48.0   48.0                                                                                                                       
2017-07-01 11:00:00   56.0   56.0                                                                                                                       
2017-07-01 12:00:00   65.0   65.0                                                                                                                       
2017-07-01 13:00:00   57.0   57.0                                                                                                                       
2017-07-01 14:00:00   46.0   46.0                                                                                                                       
2017-07-01 15:00:00   39.0   39.0                                                                                                                       
2017-07-01 16:00:00   24.0   24.0                                                                                                                       
2017-07-01 17:00:00   22.0   22.0                                                                                                                       
2017-07-01 18:00:00   np.nan   28.0                                                                                                                       
2017-07-01 19:00:00   np.nan   25.0                                                                                                                       
2017-07-01 20:00:00   38.0   38.0                                                                                                                       
2017-07-01 21:00:00   52.0   52.0                                                                                                                       
2017-07-01 22:00:00  123.0  123.0  
2017-07-01 23:00:00  np.nan  np.nan  
2017-07-02 00:00:00  np.nan  np.nan                                                                                                                        
2017-07-02 01:00:00  np.nan  np.nan                                                                                                                        
2017-07-02 02:00:00  np.nan  np.nan                                                                                                                        
2017-07-02 03:00:00  np.nan  np.nan                                                                                                                        
2017-07-02 04:00:00  np.nan  np.nan                                                                                                                       
2017-07-02 05:00:00  np.nan  np.nan                                                                                                                       
2017-07-02 06:00:00  np.nan  np.nan                                                                                                                       2017-07-02 07:00:00  np.nan  np.nan                                                                                                                           
2017-07-02 08:00:00  np.nan  np.nan                                                                                                                         
2017-07-02 09:00:00  np.nan  np.nan                                                                                                                        
2017-07-02 10:00:00  np.nan  np.nan                                                                                                                       
2017-07-02 11:00:00  np.nan  np.nan                                                                                                                       
2017-07-02 12:00:00  np.nan  np.nan                                                                                                                       
2017-07-02 13:00:00  np.nan  np.nan                                                                                                                       
2017-07-02 14:00:00  np.nan  np.nan                                                                                                                        
2017-07-02 15:00:00  np.nan  np.nan                                                                                                                       
2017-07-02 16:00:00  np.nan  np.nan                                                                                                                         
2017-07-02 17:00:00   np.nan  np.nan                                                                                                                         
2017-07-02 18:00:00   np.nan   28.0                                                                                                                       
2017-07-02 19:00:00   np.nan   25.0                                                                                                                       
2017-07-02 20:00:00   38.0   38.0                                                                                                                       
2017-07-02 21:00:00   52.0   52.0                                                                                                                       
2017-07-02 22:00:00  123.0  123.0      
2017-07-02 23:00:00  130.0  131.0  
2017-07-03 00:00:00  115.0  118.0                                                                                                                       
2017-07-03 01:00:00  126.0  128.0                                                                                                                       
2017-07-03 02:00:00   96.0   np.nan                                                                                                                       
2017-07-03 03:00:00   86.0   88.0                                                                                                                       
2017-07-03 04:00:00   77.0   75.0                                                                                                                       
2017-07-03 05:00:00   60.0   60.0                                                                                                                       
2017-07-03 06:00:00   61.0   59.0                                                                                                                       2017-07-03 07:00:00   57.0   53.0                                                                                                                          
2017-07-03 08:00:00   55.0   52.0                                                                                                                       
2017-07-03 09:00:00   47.0   48.0                                                                                                                       
2017-07-03 10:00:00   42.0   43.0                                                                                                                       
2017-07-03 11:00:00   56.0   57.0                                                                                                                       
2017-07-03 12:00:00   68.0   62.0                                                                                                                       
2017-07-03 13:00:00   56.0   57.0                                                                                                                       
2017-07-03 14:00:00   47.0   42.0                                                                                                                       
2017-07-03 15:00:00   33.0   37.0                                                                                                                       
2017-07-03 16:00:00   27.0   25.0                                                                                                                       
2017-07-03 17:00:00   24.0   20.0                                                                                                                       
2017-07-03 18:00:00   np.nan   28.0                                                       
2017-07-03 19:00:00   42.0   42.0                                                                                                                       
2017-07-03 20:00:00   42.0   42.0                                                                                                                       
2017-07-03 21:00:00   33.0   33.0                                                                                                                       
2017-07-03 22:00:00   35.0   35.0                                                                                                                       
2017-07-03 23:00:00   59.0   59.0
```

Thanks!

Edit:

Based on W-M response I was able to do the following code which works for what I want.

```
def interpolate_obs(df):
    def long_nan_series(series):
        # select this series when all values are NaNs
        all_nans = series.isnull().all()

        # and the delta is too long for interpolation
        # note: taking the last value minus the first,
        #       so this is the delta between the last NaN
        #       value and the first NaN value - there's
        #       an hour duration more until the next non-null value
        too_long = series.index[-1] - series.index[0] > pd.Timedelta("3 hours")
        return too_long & all_nans

    def get_average_value(series, mean_value, date):
        result=np.nan
        days=0       #(3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30)  
        days_mean=-1 #(1, 3, 5,  7,  9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19)
        while result!=result:
            days+=3
            ## If nothing is found within a month (15 days before, 15 days after) then stop
            if days>15:
                return np.nan
            ## Get last week
            timedelta=pd.Timedelta("%s days"%days)
            working_data=series.loc[date-timedelta:date+timedelta]
            ## Get only the ones that are the same hour
            working_data=working_data[working_data.index.hour==date.hour]

            result=working_data.mean()
            if result==result:
                return result

            ## Get surrounding three days
            days_mean+=2
            timedelta=pd.Timedelta("%s days"%days_mean)
            working_data=mean_value.loc[date-timedelta:date+timedelta]
            ## Get only the ones that are the same hour
            working_data=working_data[workinreg_data.index.hour==date.hour]

            result=working_data.mean()
            if result==result:
                return result



    mean_value=df.mean(axis=1)
    for col in df.columns:
        series=df[col]
        df_nan_group_keys = series.isnull().diff().ne(0).cumsum()
        series_long_nans = series.groupby(df_nan_group_keys).transform(long_nan_series)
        
        ## Small gaps 
        series_small_gaps=series[~series_long_nans]  
        series_small_interp = series_small_gaps.interpolate(method="linear")

        ## Long gaps. Groups them by gaps
        series_long_gaps=series[series_long_nans]
        time_dif=series_long_gaps.index.to_series().diff()
        time_dif[time_dif>pd.Timedelta("1H")]=np.nan 
        time_dif=time_dif.replace(pd.Timedelta("1H"), 0).replace(np.nan, 1)  
        time_dif=time_dif.astype(int).cumsum()
        


        ## Retrieve each gap and find the new values
        both=pd.concat([series_long_gaps, time_dif], axis=1)
        both.columns=[col, "group"]
        series_long_interp=[]
        for group, df_group in both.groupby("group"):
            series_long_interp.append(df_group.apply(lambda x: get_average_value(series, mean_value, x.name), axis=1))
        series_long_interp=pd.concat(series_long_interp)


        df[col]=pd.concat([series_small_interp, series_long_interp]).sort_index() 

    return df
```

Comment: Btw, the given data is broken. Have a look at the stock market example here on how to create an example DataFrame that others can use: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30424537/463796

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution on how to fill different NaN blocks, depending on their length:

```
# count up by one every time NaN-state flips
d31_nan_group_keys = df.D31.isnull().diff().ne(0).cumsum()

def long_nan_series(series):
    # select this series when all values are NaNs
    all_nans = series.isnull().all()

    # and the delta is too long for interpolation
    # note: taking the last value minus the first,
    #       so this is the delta between the last NaN
    #       value and the first NaN value - there's
    #       an hour duration more until the next non-null value
    too_long = series.index[-1] - series.index[0] > pd.Timedelta("3 hours")
    return too_long & all_nans

# select NaN blocks too long for interpolation
d31_long_nans = df.D31.groupby(d31_nan_group_keys).transform(select_too_long)

# interpolation method
d31_interp = df.D31.interpolate(method="linear")

# TODO: other fill method depending on last week
d31_other = df.D31.fillna(method="ffill")

# mix them together
d31_res = d31_other.where(d31_long_nans, d31_interp)
```

I've left for you to compute `d31_other` to fill the NaNs the other way (from last weeks values), as it's a different problem. I suggest to open a new question if you get stuck trying to implement that.

Comment: Thanks! your answer helped me get the ground working and I was able to complete the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

df.interpolate(method="time")  should solve your problem
Just make sure your index in datetime (df>index = pd.to_datetime(df>index)